# Cell button keeps creating new every time utableview reloads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

The apps is searching for beacon in the same range. Im showing all beacons in UTTableView. The problem i have now is that every time the uitableview reloads its creates a new button. This makes the app be very slow and takes very much CPU power.

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Tag"];

    AXABeacon *beacon = [[AXABeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [self.bleDevices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    button.tag = indexPath.row;

    //set the position of the button
    //NSLog(@"innan if %@", [self.setButton objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        NSLog(@"Skapar en ny ");
        //NSLog(@"Inne i if %@", [self.setButton objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
        button.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x + 190, cell.frame.origin.y + 7, 100, 30);
        [button setTitle:@"Radera" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteCell:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
        [self.setButton addObject:beacon];
    NSLog(@"Efter if %@", [self.setButton objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
    //Här är det slut på sätta knappar

    //Definerar veriabler
    UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
    UILabel *uuidLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
    UILabel *rssiLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    UILabel *majorLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:4];
    UILabel *minorLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:5];

    //Ger variabler ett värde
    titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.name];
    uuidLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", beacon.uuidString];
    rssiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RSSI: %@", [beacon.rssi stringValue]];
    minorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Minor: %@", beacon.minor];
    majorLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Major: %@", beacon.major];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

    //Anpassar text till storlek av box
    uuidLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a new button every time you dequeue a cell. Two ways to fix this.

1. Create a `UITableViewCell` subclass that creates and adds the button in its `init` method.
2. Worse solution: reference the button with a tag. Looks like you are trying to use the button to reference the row it is in so you can't do it this way anyway. You need to use solution #1

Comment: I think the code i have in the question is the `UITableViewCell` method. @dima

Comment: @dima asked you to subclass UITableViewCell, this means create your own class that derives from it. This new cell class would then create your button. Your problem now is that you're dequeuing the cell and then adding a button. Dequeueing is not the same as creating.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's because you're alloc init every button, labels and beacon. Do that when cell is not there.

```
if(!cell)
{
   beacon = [[AXABeacon alloc] init];
   button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
   // and so on
}
```

Hope this helps.